# MYSQL average on every single day

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to find the averaging based on each day temperature value. How can I do so?

```
SELECT Timestamp, Value 
FROM aReadings 
WHERE type = 'Temperature' AND Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
SELECT DATE(Timestamp), AVG(Value)
FROM aReadings 
WHERE 
    type = 'Temperature' 
    AND Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY DATE(Timestamp)
```

`DATE(expr)` Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.